# Positional indexing in F#

Tags: list, indexing, f#

Given a list, I would like to produce a second list of elements selected from the first one.

For example:

```
let l1 = [1..4]
let n = [0; 2]
l1.[n]
```

should return `1` and `3`, the first and third element of `l1`.
Unfortunately, it returns an error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
int but here has type int list
```

Now, I wonder, does exist a way to pass an argument `n` representing a list or, even better, an expression?

Comment: `n |> List.map (List.nth l1)`?

Comment: Is there a broader reason as to why you want to do this?  Accessing a list element by index is O(n) so it isn't a terribly good thing to do repeatedly.

Comment: I used it quite often in R programming. I found it quite practical. I know that those languages as quite different, hence I am working on my mindset. A possible problem to solve could be access one element yes and one element no of a list.

Comment: If you need random access, use arrays rather than lists. That's what they are for.

Comment: Thanks @scrwtp, I will use them for sure when I will use random access!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# doesn't offer syntactical support for that sort of indexing. You can ask for a continuous slice of an array like below, but it doesn't cover your exact scenario.

```
let a = [|1 .. 4|]
let b = a.[0..2]
// returns [|1; 2; 3|]
```

You can easily write a function for that though:

```
let slice<'a> (indices: int list) (arr: 'a array) = 
    [| for idx in indices do yield arr.[idx] |]

slice [0; 2] a 
// returns [| 1; 3 |]
```

I'm leaving proper handling of out-of-bounds access as an exercise ;)

Comment: Really interesting! Why do think that this approach is not supported in F#? Is it that inefficient? Thanks for the example!

Comment: It's just a rare feature to see in a general-purpose programming language.

Comment: @Worice This type of fancy indexing is common in languages that are domain specific to matrix manipulation. As scrwtp points it out F# is a general-purpose languages with many other data structures that serve a similar need. I  recall that you can pass a list of indices to Deedle in a similar way. However this could still be a nice feature for matrix manipulation in [Mathnet.Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html), currently the work around is  in the above Answer or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466407/how-to-shuffle-a-densematrix-in-f/40477039#40477039).

Comment: Thanks @s952163 for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

With [indexed properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/members/indexed-properties), you should be able to define this for your types: just define a `member Item with get(indexes)` which accepts a list/array. But standard lists and arrays already have `Item` defined, and you can't have two at once...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way:

```
List.map (fun index -> l1.[index]) n
```

It's inefficient for large lists, but works for me.